# How do I unset the root password in OS X 10.5?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, root

I set the OSX 10.5 root password, then figured out I didn't need to. How do I set it back to the system default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply deactivate the root user, this will also remove the root account password.

To do this, you can either run `dsenableroot -d` on the command line (logged in as an admin user), which will prompt for your admin password to disable the root user, or by choosing the option to deactivate the root user from /Applications/Utilities/Directory Utility.app´s edit menu.